# How to Use looping on PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, xampp, shuffle

Hello i have tables like this :

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName 
1234        Minjun   
1235        Nichkhun     
1236        Taecyeon     
1237        Wooyoung     
1238        Junho       
1239        Chansung
```

i used this source code :

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Employee") or die(mysql_error());

$employees = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY EmployeeID") 
or die(mysql_error());  


$letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 

$array = array(); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($employees)){ 
$array[] = $row;
} 

$i = 0; 

// Assign a letter to each employee in the correct order 
foreach($array as $Key => $row){ 
$array[$Key]["letter"] = substr($letters, $i, 1); 
$i++; 
if($i > 25){ 
$i = 0; 
} 
} 

// Shuffle the array 
shuffle($array); 

// Print each entry with correctly assigned letter and name. 
foreach($array as $row) { 
echo "<DIV>" . $row["letter"] . " = " . $row['EmployeeName'] . " </div>"; 
}


?>
```

to display random data like this :

```
E = Junho
B = Nichkhun
C = Taecyeon
F = Chansung
D = Wooyoung
A = Minjun
```

or like this :

```
B = Nichkhun
D = Wooyoung
F = Chansung
E = Junho
A = Minjun
C = Taecyeon
```

The problem is i want to display 10 type of varian random like this :

```
E = Junho
B = Nichkhun
C = Taecyeon
F = Chansung
D = Wooyoung
A = Minjun 

F = Chansung
D = Wooyoung
C = Taecyeon
E = Junho
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun

A = Minjun
D = Wooyoung
E = Junho
B = Nichkhun
F = Chansung
C = Taecyeon

D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
C = Taecyeon
A = Minjun
E = Junho
F = Chansung

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
F = Chansung
A = Minjun
E = Junho
B = Nichkhun

A = Minjun
F = Chansung
C = Taecyeon
E = Junho
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
F = Chansung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
E = Junho

E = Junho
C = Taecyeon
B = Nichkhun
F = Chansung
D = Wooyoung
A = Minjun

E = Junho
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
D = Wooyoung
F = Chansung
C = Taecyeon

D = Wooyoung
A = Minjun
C = Taecyeon
B = Nichkhun
F = Chansung
E = Junho
```

so i add codes like this :

```
  <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Employee") or die(mysql_error());

$employees = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY EmployeeID") 
or die(mysql_error());  


$letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 

$array = array(); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($employees)){ 
$array[] = $row;
} 

$i = 0; 

// Assign a letter to each employee in the correct order 
foreach($array as $Key => $row){ 
$array[$Key]["letter"] = substr($letters, $i, 1); 
$i++; 
if($i > 25){ 
$i = 0; 
} 
} 

// Shuffle the array 
shuffle($array); 

// Print each entry with correctly assigned letter and name. 
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){

foreach($array as $row) { 
echo "<DIV>" . $row["letter"] . " = " . $row['EmployeeName'] . " </div>"; 
echo "";

}
}

?>
```

but the result is like this (looping one result for 10 times):

```
C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho

C = Taecyeon
D = Wooyoung
B = Nichkhun
A = Minjun
F = Chansung
E = Junho
```

may you know where is the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your 'for loop' as below and try

```
 //shuffle($array); //Comment this line

    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    shuffle($array);
    foreach($array as $row) { 
    echo "<DIV>" . $row["letter"] . " = " . $row['EmployeeName'] . " </div>"; 
    echo "";

    }
    }
```

Comment: oh yup, it is working now. Thank you so much for your help :)